# How to know The user capture screenshot or not?

Tags: java, screenshot

I want to know that if the user take screenshot , how to stop my application?☹
Taking screenshot is almost a bug in my app because it show user the solution of game(the app is a rotation circle)!

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Like code or more information on your work ?

Comment: You can't. You can do it with JNI by writing sort of a Key Logger/Interceptor, but it's OS-dependent.

Comment: There is no way, at worst the user can take a photo with his handy - quality is low, but technically a screenshot

Comment: assuming you use either jwt, swing or javafx for your gui, you could bind an on-click event to the keyboard print button. Other than that, you propably can't.